# Switch between two color schemes for an app?

Tags: objective-c

For instance, I want light colors for all my views(background and labels) during the day and dark colors at night. The app will change its color automatically according to the time. Also the user will be able to switch to the other color scheme in settings. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Multiple colors are involved in the switch (background and labels).

Comment: This may help you. https://github.com/Draveness/DKNightVersion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have done something very similar in the recent past; an app required various, user-selectable, colour schemes.

## Theme

Create a Theme class with properties for each of your colour types. Try to stay away from describing the specific usage (`submitButtonBackgroundColor`), instead describe the purpose (this way you'll end up with much fewer colour definitions):

```
extern NSString * const ThemeChanged;

@interface Theme : NSObject

+ (Theme *)currentTheme;
+ (void)setCurrentTheme:(Theme *)theme;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *backgroundColor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *foregroundColor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *darkerForegroundColor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *lighterForegroundColor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *highlightColor;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
NSString * const ThemeChanged = @"ThemeChanged";

static Theme *_currentTheme = nil;

// Note this is not thread safe

@implementation Theme

+ (Theme *)currentTheme {
    return _currentTheme;
}

+ (void)setCurrentTheme:(Theme *)theme {
    _currentTheme = theme;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ThemeChanged object:nil];
}

@end
```

This class can then be instantiated with each of your desired schemes (one for day, one for night).

Each of your view controllers will need to access `[Theme currentTheme]` to retrieve the colours. They (your view controllers) can also register as an observer of the `ThemeChanged` notification in order to dynamically update their view's colours if/when you change the theme using `setCurrentTheme:`.

## Day/Night detection

As for updating automatically based on the time of day you could use a repeating `NSTimer` with a *reasonable* interval, check the current time and call `setCurrentTheme:` with the dark theme object you created.

```
@interface DayNightHandler : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;

@end

@implementation DayNightHandler

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(checkTime)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)checkTime {
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute
                                                                   fromDate:currentDate];

    NSLog(@"%@",components);

    // Very crude
    if (components.hour >= 18 || components.hour <= 6) {
        // set dark theme
    } else {
        // set light theme
    }
}

@end
```

You may want to swap out the crude day/night check for something a bit more solid, this is purely a high-level example intended to get you on the right track.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer that actually addresses the day/night part of the question.  This is a pretty solid foundation, and arguably could be complemented with extensions/subclasses for all of the UI elements you wish to set to the theme.  The best part is, the `Theme` class and its notification mean that we can reuse that aspect of it for user-selected themes even if we're not changing with day/night cycle.

Answer (score -3):

Create one property named `appColor` of type `UIColor` in AppDelegate.h File.
Create its custom getter, and add your logic for timing as well as selection from settings.

Just set color by using,

```
self.view.backgroundColor = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).appColor
```

this will execute your custom getter method and return color as per your logic.

Comment: Thanks but what it there are multiple colors needed to change?

Comment: This answer doesn't even address what is probably the most pertinent question asked...

Comment: @KingJ you can implement multiple color logic as well in getter of appColor property, this is purly depends on logic, whenever color is required just you need to get that color by using  ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).appColor , thanks